# Am I using the django if template tag wrong?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have this in my Django 1.2 template:

```
{% for m in model.related.iterator %}
    {% if "str" or "Str" in m %} 
         {{m}}//I don't want anything here but put this in so I could see the output 
    {%else%} 
         {% if forloop.last %} 
           {% customtag "var" %} 
         {% endif %} 
    {% endif %} 
{% endfor %}
```

I get the value of `{{m}}` no matter if it contains `"str"`, `"Str"` or neither of them. Also, if I take out the `or` and compare one string it works but I would like to compare both without another `else if`. Any way to do that?

Answer (score 3):

I believe what you want is

```
{% if "str" in m or "Str" in m %}
```

however, Glyn's answer would also work

Comment: Yep, `{% if "str" or "Str" in m %}` is saying `if "str"` which evaluates to True, so the rest of the if statement never even gets evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

try...

```
{% if "STR" in m|upper %}
    Do something
{% endif %}
```